# Yii2 Register Asset Files (js) at the end of all js files

Tags: php, jquery, yii2, assetbundle

I am trying to add a `js-file` to my view via `AssetBundles` at the very end of the page.

When using the static approach with `MyAssetBundle::register($this->view)`, I could use `jsOptions` with `'position' => \yii\web\View::POS_END`, which works as it should.

However, I need to set some variables dynamically. Therefore I tried to work with an instance of the `MyAssetBundle` class and `registerAssetFiles` instead of `register`.

**My approach:**

```
$myAsset= new MyAssetBundle();
//...do some stuff with the variables (+ load different css/js files based on the variables)
$myAsset->registerAssetFiles($this->view);
```

Basically it still works, the problem is that the `js-files` are on top of all `js-files`, so f.e. if I use `jQuery` in my `js-file`, I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined` because the jQuery File is included after my file.

I'm pretty new to Yii - is there a way that I can include my files at the end of the `js` part?

Comment: you can do it the old fashion way of using script tags in the header of your app

Comment: what do you mean by **set some variables dynamically**?

Comment: @madalinivascu I override the `$css` and  `$js` variables to include different files (depends on the view) -- The whole `AssetBundle` is part of a widget and I want to load it with different js/css files based on where I need the widget

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a whole day of research and checking dependencies, I came to a quite simple solution to the problem. Both of the answers above are correct - so I voted them up, but they did not fully fit my specific needs.

The `AssetBundle` class comes up with a variable `$depends` and a variable `$jsOptions` - which did not work at it's own. But while checking dependencies I realized that the `$jsOptions` have a param `depends` as well.

So I created a constructor, that sets the `depends` in `$jsOptions` to all my needed Assets, which have to be included before my files.

**My solution:**

```
class AjaxPanelAsset extends AssetBundle
{
   public $basePath    = '@webroot';
   public $baseUrl     = '@web';
   public $css = [

   ];
   public $js = [

   ];

   public $depends = [
    'yii\web\YiiAsset',
    'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset',
    'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapPluginAsset',
   ];

   public function setCSSJSFiles($css,$js)
   {
    $this->css = array($css);        
    $this->js = array($js);
   }

   public function __construct(){
    $this->jsOptions= ['depends' => $this->depends];
   }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are 5 positions in Yii asset module

> const POS_HEAD = 1;
>
> const POS_BEGIN = 2;
>
> const POS_END = 3;
>
> const POS_READY = 4;
>
> const POS_LOAD = 5;

If you want to place a file in the bottom of whole file,
you can user

> $this->view->registerJsFile('/path/to/js', POS_LOAD);
>
> $this->view->registerCssFile('/path/to/css', POS_LOAD);

If you want to place it at the top of all js file
you could choose a suitable POS
In your question, I think it would help you

> $this->view->registerJsFile('/path/to/jquery', POS_BEGIN);

Comment: Both of the answers above are correct - so I voted them up, but unfortunately they did not fully fit my specific needs.

Answer (score 0):

> However, I need to set some variables dynamically.

You should not do this. Asset bundles are considered as a simple entities for storing (static) assets paths and setting - if you start adding some logic into these classes, it will start breaking in some cases (like combining and compressing assets).

If you really have multiple scenarios, you should create multiple assets bundles and register correct one. You may crate some helper to simplify this:

```
class AssetsHelper {

    public const SCENARIO_A = 'a';
    public const SCENARIO_B = 'b';

    public static function register(View $view, string $scenario) {
        switch ($scenario) {
            case static::SCENARIO_A:
                AssetBundleA::register($view);
                break;
            case static::SCENARIO_B:
                AssetBundleB::register($view);
                break;
            default:
                throw new InvalidArgumentException("Unsupported scenario: $scenario.");
        }
    }
}
```

And in view:

```
AssetHelper::register($this, $scenario);
```

---

If your asset rules are to complicated and/or dynamic to create separate asset bundle class for each case, you should probably resign from using asset bundles and use [`registerCssFile()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-view#registerCssFile()-detail) and [`registerJsFile()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-view#registerJsFile()-detail) directly.

Comment: Both of the answers above are correct - so I voted them up, but unfortunately they did not fully fit my specific needs.